# Como trabajar con varias bases de datos usando entity framework core

Tags: asp.net-core

yo tengo una duda, sera que se puede trabajar con varias bases de datos en una solucion de asp.net core utilizando entity framework core, lo que pasa es que yo ya tengo creadas las bases de datos y lo de database first pues lo entiendo un poco, lo que no encuentro como hacer es que bueno tengo unas pantallas desarrolladas en php y ahi uno directamente trabaja con el sql y puede manejar de manera mas facil usar una base o otra, pero aca en el trabajo se quiere migrar a asp.net core y usar .net core para hacerlo multiplataforma, pero como se debe hacer uso de entity framework core para el manejo de la base de datos, no se como usar en una sola solución o aplicación, todas las bases de datos que utilizamos con php, podrian guiarme un poco con respecto a esto, gracias.

Comment: Si puedes utilizar más de una BD en una solución ASP.Net core, basta con agregar un string de conexión para cada BD que tengas y una clase contexto que utilize tu string de conexión.

Comment: podrías darme un ejemplo por favor

Comment: Si el requerimiento es utilizar .net core para hacerlo multiplataforma, ¿porque utilizar entity framework core? Existen alternativas (Micro ORMs) que te pueden ir mejor en este caso para hacer la migración.

Answer (score 2):

Un ejemplo sencillo. Tenemos una BD para Trabajadores y una para Entidades, y en el controlador de Trabjadores quiero un listado de Entidades para mostrar.

El primer paso es agregar un string de conexión para cada BD que utilizas. Esto se muestra en **appsettings.json**

```
{
"ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Identity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"TrabajadoresConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Trabajadores;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true",
"EntidadesConnection": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=Entidades;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
},
"Logging": {
  "IncludeScopes": false,
  "LogLevel": {
    "Default": "Warning"
  }
}
```

}

Como ves en ese ejemplo estoy usando 3 Bases de Datos, Identity y su cadena de conexión se llama DefaultConnection, Trabajadores TrabajadoresConnection y Entidades EntidadesConnection. Al string de conexión puedes ponerle el nombre que quieras, los demás parámetros se lo debes especificar dependiendo del tipo de conexión que tengas y tu BD, en mi caso estoy utilizando localdb que es incluido por defecto en Visual Studio.

El otro paso es el Contexto de Base de datos, en mi caso cree uno para cada BD. Creas una clase en el directorio Data de tu proyecto similar a esto:

```
public class EntidadesContext : DbContext
{
    public EntidadesContext (DbContextOptions<EntidadesContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<WebApplication1.Models.Entidad> Entidades { get; set; }
}
```

En tu contexto le especificas a EF las clases con las que quieres trabajar osea las tabals de tu BD.

El otro paso es declarar los contextos en **Startup.cs** te quedaría algo como esto:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddDbContext<TrabajadoresContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("TrabajadoresConnection")));

        services.AddDbContext<EntidadesContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("EntidadesConnection")));
    }
```

De esta forma puedes utilizar varios contextos o lo que se traduce a trabajar con varias conexiones en una sola App. Supongamos que quiero llamar las Entidades en una vista del controlador Trabajador.

```
 public class TrabajadorsController : Controller
{
    private readonly TrabajadoresContext _context;
    private readonly EntidadesContext _entidadesContext;

    public TrabajadorsController(TrabajadoresContext context, EntidadesContext entidadescontext)
    {
        _context = context;
        _entidadesContext = entidadescontext;
    }

public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["EntidadId"] = new SelectList(_entidadesContext.Entidades, "Id","Nombre");
        return View();
    }
```

}

En este Controlador he definido 2 contextos _context que se refiere al propio contexto TrabajadorContext y _entidadesContext para trabajar con la BD de Entidades. Vamos a suponer que en la clase Trabajador tenemos EntidadId como parámetro. Agregamos un select en al vista create para poder seleccionar la Entidad.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="EntidadId" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="EntidadId" asp-items="ViewBag.EntidadId" class="form-control"></select>
            <span asp-validation-for="EntidadId" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
```

de esta forma en el select se uestran todas las Entidades las cuales se encuentran en otra BD. Espero te sea de ayuda

Comment: Voy a probar tu solución, gracias. Creo que esta es una de las formas de hacerlo, te comento luego.

Comment: Disculpa, pero tendria que crear un contexto por cada base de datos que necesite utilizar.

Comment: Si en el ejemplo que te puse si. Pero eso no es un problema puesto que en el controlador puedes llamar a los contextos que quieras y trabajar con ellos.

Comment: Pero como hago en el controlador para decirle, mira necesito trabajar con este contexto, digamos que sea segun como se han logueado, por ejemplo se loguea un usuario pero este necesita usar solo la base de datos X por decir asi, pero otro usuario que se loguee necesita usar la base de datos Y, como decirle al controlador que contexto debe usar, segun el usuario que se ha logueado.